# PHP equation within html table row, or in database itself

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a site with a CSV upload, which pushes everything in the CSV to a temp table and then splits into smaller tables.

Currently, I have a display page that displays all of that info in HTML tables. Some sections, however, need to have a formulaic representation. In other words, as seen in the screenshot below, meter volume is divided by tester volume and the sum of that is multiplied by the tester accuracy. That number is divided by 100 to give the corrected accuracy.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code I have but it's not loading my web page and I think the PHP might be wrong in establishing the variables:

```
<table style="width:100%; border:none;
border-collapse:collapse;">
<? php

$test1FormA = $row['test1MeterVol'] / $row['test1TesterVol'];
$test1FormB = $test1FormA * $row['test1Accuracy'];
$test1FinalForm = $test1FormB / 100;

?>

    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Meter Volume: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Tester Volume: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Tester Accuracy: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1Accuracy'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Corrected Accuracy: </td>
        <td><? echo $test1FinalForm;?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is currently no corrected accuracy in the database, so I wanted to find either a way to do it per line, like above, or a way to do that upon every CSV upload. There are 8 tests, so it would have to do that formula for 8 different fields per 5 records in the CSV upon upload. I currently have the CSV uploading into the temp table with a large insert statement.

Is there a way to just do this in the table row with PHP?

UPDATE: Screenshot of new results

[image]

UPDATE: Code for averaging issue

```
<?php 
        $sum=0;
        for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){ 
            $testFormA = $row["test".$i."MeterVol"] / $row["test".$i."TesterVol"]; 
                $testFormB = $testFormA * $row["test".$i."Accuracy"]; 
                $testFinalForm = $testFormB / 100;
                $sum += $testFinalForm; 
                echo"$sum";                                     
        ?>
        <td><?php echo round($testFinalForm,3) ?>%</td>


        <?php }
        $average = $sum / 8;
        echo"$average";
        ?>

        <td><?php echo round($average,3)?>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: can you please var_dump $row['test1Accuracy'] we cant help you out without knowing the content of each variable

Comment: Test1accuracy is 100. Those fields are all integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you need. But the most important part is that you will need a loop structure to build your table with a pretty code, without repeating everything over and over.

In your case, you can use the following code to build your whole last row for all 8 tests:

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){ 
            $testFormA = $row["test".$i."MeterVol"] / $row["test".$i."TesterVol"]; 
            $testFormB = $testFormA * $row["test".$i."Accuracy"]; 
            $testFinalForm = $testFormB / 100;
?>
          <td><?php echo $testFinalForm ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Instead of accessing indexes like "test4MeterVol" you use $i to build the index string to access the right value in each loop iteration.

Doing the equations inside the loop will give you different values based on each test.

Based on this code and the way to build indexes to access your data you should be able to build the other rows, which are much simpler.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! Thank you

Comment: Sorry, Quick question? This works, but It displays all values in one row. I have 8 different <Td> rows that have the corrected accuracy. Would I be able to label each one from that loop?

Comment: The code in my answer generates 8 <td>, which would be the columns for your last table row. I don't know what you want to label. If you just want to label the row at the left, you can just add a <td> manually outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I think I said that in a confusing manner. I updated my original question with a new screenshot at the bottom. I got it to work for the <Td> row, but it skews the whole table now, I'm assuming because of the extra decimals. Is there a way to format that or will I just need to play with table styles?

Comment: You can use "round" to round the numbers to just a few decimals, for example with round($testFinalForm, 4)

Comment: Ah, that got it! Thanks again

Comment: out of curiosity is there a way to average those 8 corrected accuracy values for the final 'Overall' column?

Comment: Sure, you can initialize a variable $sum=0 before the loop. Then inside the loop you do $sum+= $testFinalForm;

And after the loop you can get the average with $average = $sum / 8;

Comment: Thank you, I set those just like you said but it returns NAN as the average so I echoed $sum inside the loop and it actually prints out all 8 rather than an actual sum.

Comment: Make sure you used += operator in the loop instead of just = , and that it is below the line that calculates the value. Update the question with the new code if possible, so I can check it.

Comment: It seems just fine. Just a suggestion, you don't need to use echo "$variable" you can just use echo $variable

Comment: And if you want to print the sum in each cell, you should echo it inside the <td>. Otherwise they will appear above the table.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. I didn't know if the fact that the 8th corrected accuracy was NAN so that was affecting the average, but when the $sum variable printed all 8 numbers in a line I thought something might be wrong in my syntax

Comment: Oh  sorry, yes, the last one being NaN will make the sum and average be NaN. You should avoid the NaN value in your formula (avoid dividing by zero for example)

Comment: Oh I see. The whole last column is 0 on this one unfortunately, so that caused the corrected accuracy to be 0

Comment: Well, it's NaN, not zero. Maybe you can just place a big if around all the loop content to avoid showing a column if testerVol is zero, because it would break your math.

Comment: And in that case, instead of dividing by 8, you should count how many times you looped, and divide by that variable

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that then!